# What are the formal necessary and sufficient conditions for u-sub to work?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, substitution

My book made the interesting claim that, if $x=\varphi(u)$ is our u-sub function, the technique of substitution will only hold if:

1. It is a bijection onto the domain of integration (this makes sense)
2. It is continuously differentiable
3. Its derivative is nowhere zero on the interior

We will be using the Riemann integral here. I am unsure if $2)$ can be weakened, or if $3$ is strictly necessary - even though I pretty much buy the book's argument, I have heard conditions $2,3$ nowhere else before so I want to check with the community if this is accurate. The book is Courant's Differential and Integral Calculus - it's good, but not 100% rigorous!

Their argument, paraprashed:

> Take $I_x=[a,b]\subset\Bbb R$. Suppose there exists some $\varphi:I_u\to I_x$ which is a bijection and $I_u$ is compact. In the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$, we can substitute, taking the tagged partitions in $x,u$ as $(x_n,t_n),(u_n,s_n)$: $$\begin{align}\int_{I_x}f(x)\,dx=\sum f(t_n)(x_{n+1}-x_n)\overset{1}{=}&\sum (f\circ\varphi)(s_n)(\varphi(u_{n+1})-\varphi(u_n))\\\overset{2}{=}&\sum(f\circ\varphi)(s_n)\cdot\varphi'(\xi_n)(u_{n+1}-u_n)\\\overset{3}{\to}&\int_{I_u}(f\circ\varphi)(u)\cdot\varphi'(u)\,du\end{align}$$
> Step $1$ required $\varphi$ to be a bijection; step $2$ required $\varphi$ to be differentiable on each $(u_{n+1},u_n)$, and step $3$ required $f\circ\varphi$, $\varphi'$ to both be integrable, and for $\varphi'$to be continuous as its mean value $\xi$ needs to be squeezed to the same tagged value $s_n$, by definition of Riemann integral.

Now I am aware that if I take $2,3$, the Inverse Function Theorem guarantees that $\varphi$ is indeed a bijection and that all is well. However, in the analysis of the Riemann sum, we only require that $\varphi'(\xi)$ is non-zero; the way I see it, we could still have some point inside $I_u$ where $\varphi'$ is zero, and just make a choice of partition such that this is never the mean value - this works, right? I know that if the points where $\varphi$ has $0$ derivative are maxima or minima we lose invertibility, but if it is a point of inflection then, as far as I know, we can still have it as an invertible function. Yes, its inverse would not be differentiable at that point, but we surely don't care as only $\varphi$ is involved in the integration - right?

I'm also wondering if condition $2$ can be weakened - in the Riemann integral I believe we can choose our partitions, so perhaps it would be possible to make a choice of partition $s_n$ (with $\varphi(s_n)=t_n$) such that $s_n=\xi_n$, and the continuity of $\varphi'$ could be relaxed.

What actually **are** the needed conditions? And if Courant is completely correct, I'd appreciate it if someone could correct my overthinking here!

Side-note: I have not studied Lebesgue integration all that much - does U-sub still work there?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $\phi$ is continuously differentiable then $\int_a ^b f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x) dx = \int^{\phi(a)}_{\phi(b)} f(x) dx$. It is not necessary for $\phi$ to be a bijection or for the derivative not to vanish.  The proof is just an application of the FTC, you can find it [on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: @MatthewTowers He also shows that proof... but verbatim he writes "we assume $u=\psi(x)$ is monotonic and of non-vanishing derivative" - why might he have spent almost two pages if his result is incorrect?

Comment: I'm also trying to go in the opposite direction: if we *begin* with $\int f(x)\,dx$, we want to arrive at $\int f(\phi(u))\cdot\phi'(u)\,du$ - does that change anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't thought your thinking through completely but u-sub is essentially a special case of the (Jacobi) transformation theorem:

Let $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be an open set and $\phi : \Omega \to \phi(\Omega) \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ a diffeomorphism. Then $f$ is integrable on $\phi(\Omega)$ iff $x \mapsto f(\phi(x)) |\det(J_\phi(x))|$ is integrable on $\Omega$ and in this case we have
$$
\int_{\phi(\Omega)}f(x) dx = \int_\Omega f(\phi(x)) |\det{J_\phi(x)}| dx
$$
where $J_\phi(x)$ denotes the jacobian matrix of $\phi$.

A diffeomorphism is a bijection which is everywhere continuously differentiable with continuously differentiable inverse. Regular u-sub is the $\Bbb R$ case of this theorem.

The theorem doesn't have a standalone article on the English wikipedia, but it's listed under the integration by substitution article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) along with other generalizations and how the situation looks for the Lebesgue integral.

Taking this into account: your conclusion that $\phi'$ may be $0$ at some point is correct - this is the generalization via Sard's theorem. You may also relax the condition that $\phi'$ is continuous - but this brings with it the new condition of $\phi^{-1}$ being continuous (and having to exist).

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to Sard's Theorem. I would dearly like to see the proof of this - but "Jacobi transformation theorem" gives me links to propability and statistics... where might I find a proof, do you know?

Comment: Ah, it seems like the name I used is just common in Germany. Look for "change of variable formula". The one for probability theory is in basically the same theorem or a special case thereof - just expressed a bit differently. One proof of the specific theorem I stated can be found in Spivak's calculus on manifolds on page 67 (you can probably find a proof in most books on calculus on manifolds or advanced real analysis texts - although a lot of them probably involve differential forms. You can also look at books on measure theory and "pushforward measures".)

Comment: Excuse me - for what reason do you take the absolute value of the determinant? This certainly causes errors for even a $1D$ change of variables - $\phi'$ may well be negative...

Comment: Is this perhaps a Lebesgue - vs - Riemann thing? The Riemann integral certainly doesn't care about the orientation of an interval...

Comment: It indeed does not. Note that we never change the orientation in the transformation. e.g. consider $\phi(x) = b-x+a$ as a diffeomorphism on $I=(a,b)$, then the theorem tells us that:
$$
\int_{\phi(I)} f(x) dx = \int_I f(b-x+a) |-1| dx = \int_I f(b-x+a) dx
$$
which is true, since $\phi(I)=I$. It basically says that it doesn't care whether you're summing from front to back or back to front.

Comment: I have not studied the Lebesgue integral all that much - I know it partitions the range of $f$, rather than the domain - so the integral over $I$ in fact truly is independent of the order of summation, and **not** taking the absolute value would lead to errors - *but* if I am doing a Riemann integral with well defined endpoints, then taking the absolute value is wrong in that case. When I see such theorems, with absolute value, and the subscript $I$ notation, I should then assume a Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Maybe an example helps. Consider the diffeomorphism from above and f(x)=x. Then we have $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$ by direct integration. If we instead use the theorem we get $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(b-x+a) dx = \int_b^a f(x) |\frac{d}{dx}(b-x+a)|dx = \int_a^b f(x) dx$ where the second to last equality is the regular u-sub you know. This has nothing to do with Lebesgue vs. Riemann.

Comment: Your final equality reads: $\int_b^a f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$, which is wrong in the integration theory that I'm familiar with

Comment: Oh sorry, I misstyped. That should read $\frac{d}{dx}(b-x+a)$ without the absolute value since as I wrote this step uses the regular u-sub.

Comment: Using the theorem, we find $\phi(\Omega)=[b,a]$, with the endpoints switched. The theorem then says: $$\int_b^a f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(b-x+a)\cdot|(-1)|\,dx=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$$Which is not true in the Riemann sense, right? So my reading of this theorem is confused, as although $\phi(I)=I$, the *orientation* must surely matter - unless we use a different integral!

Comment: No, the theorem doesn't tell you to flip the orientation: $\phi(\Omega)$ is just $I$. So you're still integrating from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Ok that’s what I was looking for! Thank you - this has been notation hell